# Error during the installation of Java: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Tags: command-line, java

I have feeling that I messed up something badly, I am a new Linux user, so I was trying to install Java…

So basically the command that I run in terminal is the following:

```
java -version
```

Error which I get

```
-bash: /usr/local/java/jdk-16/bin/java: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

I was basically following this tutorial, and I might know where's problem, but now I can't find out which one tutorial I followed up, because after I did everything it didn't worked, so I tried another one... And I can't really recall the exact path where I was creating those changes(in which directory). I just know that I was going into /exec/ and there were some other files that I made changes to with nano, I remember that I added something like `$JAVA_HOME = ....` and then something.

If someone can help, I'd be grateful

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the outputs of commands `file /usr/local/java/jdk-16/bin/java` and `uname -m`. Why are you trying to install java by any other means than `apt`?

Answer (score 2):

I actually fixed this problem by doing following:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

This command shows each installation of Java along with its installation path:

```
Output:

There are 4 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java      1111      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java      1111      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-16-oracle/bin/java             1091      manual mode
* 3            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081      manual mode
  4            /usr/local/java/jdk-16/bin/java                  1         manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 2
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-16-oracle/bin/java to provide /usr/bin/java (java) in manual mode
```

I choosed 2nd one and copied the path to it then did following:

```
sudo nano /etc/environment
```

and inside that file added following:

```
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-16-oracle/bin/java "
```

I reloaded file to apply previous commands:

```
source /etc/environment
```

and after running the `java -version` everything was okay.

Answer (score 1):

From [mkyong](https://mkyong.com/java/bash-usr-bin-java-cannot-execute-binary-file-exec-format-error/)'s blog:

> ##### 1. Problem – Download the wrong JDK build
>
> The error Exec format error means we download the wrong JDK build for
> a specific platform.

Download the appropriate JDK for your CPU architecture.

In my case, I dowloaded the one with suffix aarch64 by mistake. Instead it was x64 as usual.

<sub>Run `lscpu` to find the cpu architecture.</sub>